# Google map not showing up with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am trying to display locations on google map dynamically. Here is the scenario. User will select an option from select box to group by either "City" or "Country".

List of addresses will come in a list view. This works fine. When user clicks on address, it should be displayed on Google map. I am passing lat and lng as parameters using `ngRoute`. Please find below my code:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <base href="/"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="addLocApp">
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3" ng-controller="AddressController">
              <label>Group By: </label>
              <select ng-model="data.select" ng-change="update(data.select)">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                <option value="city">City</option>
                <option value="country">Country</option>
              </select>
              <div class="list-group">
                <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in addresses">
                  <label>{{ key }}</label>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                      <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="addrDetail in value">
                        <a href="/detail/{{addrDetail.lat}}/{{addrDetail.lng}}" class="list-group-item">
                            <p>                             
                                {{addrDetail.address}}
                                {{addrDetail.city}}, {{addrDetail.country}}
                                {{addrDetail.postalCode}}
                            </p>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-9">
                <div ng-view></div>             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATjcJN-kXWfGk0_pcVWijVFKnBMuBarXk&language=en" defer"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>       
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>     
        <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>             
        <script src="js/service.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var addLocApp = angular.module('addLocApp', ['ngRoute', 'AddressService'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when("/", {
          templateUrl: 'map.html',
          controllerAs: 'AddressController'
        }).
        when("/detail/:lat/:lng/", {
          templateUrl: 'map.html',
          controllerAs: 'MapController'
        }).
        otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

addLocApp.constant('_',
    window._
);

addLocApp.controller('AddressController', function ($scope, LocationData, _) {
    $scope.status;
    $scope.addresses;
    getLocationDetails();

    function getLocationDetails() {
        LocationData.getAddress()
            .success(function (addr) {
                $scope.addresses = addr;
                $scope.orig = angular.copy($scope.addresses);
                console.log($scope.addresses);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }

    $scope.update = function(val){
        if(val == 'city'){
            $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
            $scope.addresses = _.groupBy($scope.data, function(d){return d.city});      
        }else{
            $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
            $scope.addresses = _.groupBy($scope.data, function(d){return d.country});           
        }


    }

});

addLocApp.controller('MapController', function ($scope, $window, $route, $routeParams, _) {

    $window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
    });

    var param1 = $routeParams.lat;
    var param2 = $routeParams.lng;

    console.log(param1+ " ::: "+ param2);

    var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 4,
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(param1,param2),
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
              }

              $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); 
});
```

**map.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MapController" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

I tried with solutions like giving height and width 100%, calling initMap function to initialize it but none of them worked.

Google map is being added in DOM. I've checked this in developer tools. But the map is not showing on page. I am using bootstrap as well.

**Is there an issue with styling or something else ? Why map is not showing up ?**

[image]

Comment: Any errros in the console? Can you provide `main.css`?

Comment: try to set the size in pixels, e.g.: 300x300. In case if your map will appear, you need to dive deep into css.

Comment: @VasylRomanchak- yes giving height and width in pixel works. But what's the reason ? Google map is responsive then why height and width in percentage does not work ? Is there an issue with bootstrap ?